# How to create attributes on a Service Order through Web Services

Tags: attributes, acumatica, endpoint

I had to create my own Web Service Endpoint for Service Orders.  Here is the WSDL:  https://imagineersllc.acumatica.com/(W(7))/entity/PileraAPI/19.100.0122?wsdl&company=Imagineers%20LLC%20-%20Prototype  I added Attributes to it following an example I found under Stock Items in the Default Endpoint.

I added attributes to the Service Order type and when I try to populate the attributes in my API they remain blank.  The Service Order gets created just fine it just does not populate the attributes.

I've tried renaming the attributes and using the code vs the description in my code.

```
string sServiceOrderType = "MRO";           // Only type supported
string sCustomer = "1003";
string sBranchLocation = "PROPMGMT";        // Only location available
string sWorkflowStage = "ACKNOWLEDGED";
DateTime dDate = DateTime.Parse("7/1/2019");
string sExternalReference = "WO-2345";   
string sDescription = "Service Order from Pilera API";
bool bOverride = true;      // Used to make Contact and Address editable
string sCompanyName = "DSD Business Systems";
string sAttention = "John Wiles";
string sPhone = "(858) 550-5900";
string sEmail = "johnw@dsdinc.com";
string sAddressLine1 = "1225 Rosemarie Way";
string sAddressLine2 = "";
string sCity = "Chesapeake";
string sState = "VA";
string sPostalCode = "23322";
DateTime dPromisedDate = DateTime.Parse("7/21/2019");
string sSeverity = "Low";
string sPriority = "High";
string sComment = "Comment created by API";
bool bHold = true;
string sCategory = "GENERALREPAIR";       
string sCommunity = "Deerfield Condominium Assoc.";
string sContact = "Annamma George";
string sContactPhone = "860-656-6603";
string sContactLocation = "268 Richard Street #1 Newington, CT 06111";

ServiceOrders ServiceOrdersToBeCreated = new ServiceOrders
{
    ServiceOrderType = new StringValue { Value = sServiceOrderType },
    Customer = new StringValue { Value = sCustomer },
    BranchLocation = new StringValue { Value = sBranchLocation },
    WorkflowStage = new StringValue { Value = sWorkflowStage },
    Date = new DateTimeValue { Value = dDate },
    ExternalReference = new StringValue { Value = sExternalReference },
    Description = new StringValue { Value = sDescription },
    Hold = new BooleanValue { Value = bHold },
    PromisedDate = new DateTimeValue { Value = dPromisedDate },
    Severity = new StringValue { Value = sSeverity },
    Priority = new StringValue { Value = sPriority },
    Category = new StringValue { Value = sCategory },
    Override = new BooleanValue { Value = bOverride },
    CompanyName = new StringValue { Value = sCompanyName },
    Attention = new StringValue { Value = sAttention },
    Phone = new StringValue { Value = sPhone },
    Email = new StringValue { Value = sEmail },
    AddressLine1 = new StringValue { Value = sAddressLine1 },
    AddressLine2 = new StringValue { Value = sAddressLine2 },
    City = new StringValue { Value = sCity },
    State = new StringValue { Value = sState },
    PostalCode = new StringValue { Value = sPostalCode },
    Comment = new StringValue { Value = sComment },
    Attributes = new[]
    {
        new AttributeValue
        {
            AttributeID = new StringValue { Value = "Community" },
            Value = new StringValue { Value = sCommunity }
        },
        new AttributeValue
        {
            AttributeID = new StringValue { Value = "Contact" },
            Value = new StringValue { Value = sContact }
        },
        new AttributeValue
        {
            AttributeID = new StringValue { Value = "Phone" },
            Value = new StringValue { Value = sContactPhone }
        },
        new AttributeValue
        {
            AttributeID = new StringValue { Value = "Location" },
            Value = new StringValue { Value = sContactLocation }
        }
    }
};
ServiceOrders newServiceOrder = (ServiceOrders)soapClient.Put(ServiceOrdersToBeCreated);
```

Service Order is created without attributes.  No error messages received.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what Support provided:

```
try
{
    ServiceOrders newServiceOrder = (ServiceOrders)client.Put(ServiceOrdersToBeCreated);

    List<AttributeValue> attrList = new List<AttributeValue>();
    foreach (AttributeValue attrVal in newServiceOrder.Attributes)
    {
        AttributeValue attr = new AttributeValue();
        attr.ID = attrVal.ID;
        switch(attrVal.AttributeID.Value)
        {
            case "Community":
                attr.Value = new StringValue { Value = sCommunity };
                break;
            case "Contact":
                attr.Value = new StringValue { Value = sContact };
                break;
            case "Phone":
                attr.Value = new StringValue { Value = sContactPhone };
                break;
            case "Location":
                attr.Value = new StringValue { Value = sContactLocation };
                break;

            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Attribute Not Found!");
                break;
        }
        attrList.Add(attr);
    }
    newServiceOrder.Attributes = attrList.ToArray();

    newServiceOrder = (ServiceOrders)client.Put(newServiceOrder);
}
```